# Gradle how to configure build file to create Spring boot jar and spring web-mvc war from same project

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot, gradle-plugin

I am in need of creating a spring boot jar and spring web mvc war from same project to run in two different environments. I have tried making single war working in both the environments, but spring boot jars are creating problem in container(non spring-boot env), so it is better to have different jar/war for both the environments.

Now in spring mvc war I don't want to include spring-boot jars(starter and tomcat-starter). Similarly in spring boot jar I don't want to include container specific jar like javax-servlet-api.jar which are needed for spring-mvc war.

How to make these 2 different set of dependencies working in same gradle file and use war and spring-boot plugin to create war and jar as build output.

I am new to gradle, please help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle file, changes below

For war,

```
    apply plugin: 'war'

    war {
        baseName = 'name of the project'
        group = group
        manifest {
           attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Title Of Project'
        }
    }
```

For Jar,

```
    apply plugin: 'jar'

    jar {
        baseName = 'name of the project'
        version =  version
        group = group
        manifest {
           attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Title Of Project'
       }
    }
```